# What is the Lebesgue measure of $\left\{(x,y)\in[0,1)^2:\left\|(x,y)-(x_0,y_0)\right\|<\varepsilon\right\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I know how the Lebesgue measure of a ball in arbitrary dimension can be computed, but I struggle to find a suitable expression for the following measure: Let $(x_0,y_0)\in[0,1)^2$ and $$A:=\left\{(x,y)\in[0,1)^2:\left\|(x,y)-(x_0,y_0)\right\|<\varepsilon\right\}.$$ Let $\lambda$ denote the Lebesgue measure on $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$.

> How can we determine $\lambda^{\otimes2}(A)$?

Note that \begin{equation}\begin{split}A_x&:=\left\{y\in[0,1):(x,y)\in A\right\}\\&=\left\{y\in[0,1):(y-y_0)^2<\varepsilon^2-(x-x_0)^2\right\}\end{split}\tag1\end{equation} for all $x\in[0,1)$. Now I guess we need to treat $\varepsilon^2-(x-x_0)^2\ge0$ and $\varepsilon^2-(x-x_0)^2<0$ separately. In the first case, $$A_x=\left(y_0-\sqrt{\varepsilon^2-(x-x_0)^2},y_0+\sqrt{\varepsilon^2-(x-x_0)^2}\right)\cap[0,1)\tag2.$$ However, I don't know how to proceed.

Finally we obviously need to use $$\lambda^{\otimes2}(A)=\int_{[0,\:1)}\lambda({\rm d}x)\lambda(A_x)\tag3.$$

Comment: You mean that $A$ is that portion of the disk centered at $(x_0,y_0 )$ of radius $\epsilon$ which is contained in the unit square $[0,1)^2$?

Comment: @lcv I guess we can phrase it in that way, yes.

Comment: Well then, if the disk lies entirely in the square you're done. Otherwise you have to check all cases and remove from the disk the corresponding portion. There are, I'd say, eight cases, of two types.